# My outdoor lights on whole day and night. I can't find any switches for them

Tags: switch, light

My outdoor wall lights always work. I can't find any switches for them, and I already tried every switch in the house. When I use one of switches near porch switch, nothing happens. I only noticed lights turned off when handymen came to repair pool things, and he turned off electricity which regards to pool. Where do you think may located switch for these outdoor lights outside of my garage?

Comment: Possible they had a day/night sensor that stop working, but not likely.  Would turn off breakers till they go off and see what else doesn't work.  Maybe whoever had them put in did not think about having a switch, just the breaker, would be weird.

Comment: It's possible that the previous owner had a home automation system and installed these lights to be switched digitally and didn't include a physical switch. There may be an blank wall plate somewhere that contains a WiFi (or other wireless protocol) enabled switch that is used to turn them on/off. (Yes, some are UL listed for installation in a junction box.) It may be set to turn on when power is restored and you simply have no way of turning them off.

Comment: Is it not bad enough to find a switch that does nothing, now we have to worry about hidden WiFi switches.

Comment: Alternately, why don't you just fix the broken day/night sensor or the broken motion sensor?  Better day/night sensors are made to fail "on", for the simple reason that the exact same units are used on municipal street lights, and city maintenance people mostly work during the day.  Although they make a variant designed to fail "off".

Comment: Thank you for your tips, guys! Unfortunately, I suck at all of this electric stuff area. I have only one switch that doesn't do anything, and it near the front door. Maybe this one that I need to repair? We also have a security system, and there are a lot of different buttons. Also, there is something looks like wi-fi router and one white box attached to the wall, and it doesn't have any buttons. Sorry for this poor description, I rent this house, and I moved only recently:)

Comment: Rental places need to have an electrician to do most work, renters/landlords only allowed to do simple replacements, replace light bulbs, maybe switches/outlets, anything else need the electrician.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I thought maybe there is a hidden switch in the house, so I will not need to call electrician.

Comment: Can you find a circuit breaker in your breaker panel that turns them off?

Comment: **Just get a new fixture** with a dusk till dawn. *That* you can do, presuming you know how to kill the power. Adding a timer or a switch is not novice level. First **make sure the senor is not covered** by a little plastic cap (this comes with the light to defeat the sensor, for if you do want it always on).

Comment: Do you need the lights at night? Assuming bulbs (as opposed to integrated leds), you could just unscrew the bulbs a bit to turn them off.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica But also better for a street light to fail on and waste a little energy than to fail off and have an unsafe street.

Answer (score 2):

One way to find the culprit is to check ALL switches and junction boxes on the pertinent circuit.

If you are new and cautious about DIY electrical work, get an experienced DIY friend to do this with you. Working with open boxes on live circuits is dangerous. If you are not the home owner you need to contact the landlord.

1. Switch off all circuits at the panel.
2. Switch them on one at a time and determine which circuit applies to those lights.
3. With only that circuit on, and others off, determine the switches and junction boxes wired to it. For this, use a "proximity" voltage tester (not expensive), and open each box. Mark every such light, switch and receptacle with a piece of (painter's) tape.
4. In all switch boxes for this circuit, near the lights, check so see if any wire that possibly continues from the box to the outdoor lights is wired "permanently on". They may originally have been wired through a switch that is later circumvented.

If so, you are likely able to interrupt the wire to the lights and confirm that the lights are fed by it. Before unwiring the feed, the circuit must be switched off at the panel by the breaker, and any loose wires must then capped off before switching the breaker on again. If the lights now stay off you likely found your feed.

5. Check that all earlier marked outlets of this circuit (lights, receptacles) still have power, after interrupting the sub-circuit for the problematic outdoor lights. If the feed leaving the box *only* serves your lights, you may be able to rewire it so that the lights outside go through the switch.

Report back with your findings if step 4 is not conclusive.

Comment: in paragraph 2 you reccomend breaking the law

Comment: @Jasen changed "for you" to "with you"